# Mock same method with different parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am using mockito to test my business service, and it uses a utility that i want to mock. there are at least 2-3 calls in each service method for utility with different arguments.

Is there any recommended way to use multiple `when(...).thenReturn(...)` for same method but different arguments?

I also want to use `any()` marcher as well inside. Is it possible?

Update: sample code.

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
  when(service.foo(any(), new ARequest(1, "A"))).thenReturn(new AResponse(1, "passed"));
  when(service.foo(any(), new ARequest(2, "2A"))).thenReturn(new AResponse(2, "passed"));
  when(service.foo(any(), new BRequest(1, "B"))).thenReturn(new BResponse(112, "passed"));

  c.execute();
}

public class ClassUnderTest {
  Service service = new Service();
  public void execute() {
    AResponse ar = (AResponse) service.foo("A1", new ARequest(1, "A"));
    AResponse ar2 = (AResponse) service.foo("A2", new ARequest(2, "2A"));
    BResponse br = (BResponse) service.foo("B1", new BRequest(1, "B"));
  }
}

public class Service {
  public Object foo(String firstArgument, Object obj) {
    return null; //return something
  }
}
```

Comment: This is contradicting. If you specify `any()`, you mean any, but at the same time you don't?!? Just use the appropriate matchers.

Comment: please recommend me some way. i cant create object for one of the parameter, that's why i use any() but defiantly i wouldn't work. I meant to say that i want to do something same.

Comment: Something that might have been overlooked: You cannot mix matchers and plain arguments when stubbing a mock. So `when(service.foo(any(), new ARequest(1, "A"))` should cause an error from the framework because `any()` is a matcher and `new ARequest...` is not

Answer (score 78, accepted):

One way could be to avoid being too restrictive on your arguments in order to provide all the expected results with only one `thenReturn` call.

For example let's say that I want to mock this method:

```
public String foo(String firstArgument, Object obj) {
    return "Something";
}
```

You could then mock it by providing as many results as you want like below:

```
// Mock the call of foo of any String to provide 3 results
when(mock.foo(anyString(), anyObject())).thenReturn("val1", "val2", "val3");
```

Calls to `foo` with any parameters will provide respectively "`val1`", "`val2`", then any subsequent calls will provide "`val3`".

---

In case you do care about passed values but don't want to depend on call sequence you can use `thenAnswer` to provide an answer that matches with the second argument like you currently do but with 3 different `thenReturn`.
Assuming that you have overridden the method `equals(Object o)`.

```
when(mock.foo(anyString(), anyObject())).thenAnswer(
    invocation -> {
        Object argument = invocation.getArguments()[1];
        if (argument.equals(new ARequest(1, "A"))) {
            return new AResponse(1, "passed");
        } else if (argument.equals(new ARequest(2, "2A"))) {
            return new AResponse(2, "passed");
        } else if (argument.equals(new BRequest(1, "B"))) {
            return new BResponse(112, "passed");
        }
        throw new InvalidUseOfMatchersException(
            String.format("Argument %s does not match", argument)
        );
    }
);
```

Or simply, using the methods `anyString` and `eq` as argument marchers.
Assuming that you have overridden the method `equals(Object o)`.

```
when(service.foo(anyString(), eq(new ARequest(1, "A"))))
    .thenReturn(new AResponse(1, "passed"));
when(service.foo(anyString(), eq(new ARequest(2, "2A"))))
    .thenReturn(new AResponse(2, "passed"));
when(service.foo(anyString(), eq(new BRequest(1, "B"))))
    .thenReturn(new BResponse(112, "passed"));
```

Comment: @ZeeshanBilal why? do you want to get failures if the arguments are not equal?

Comment: because in my service implementation, there are possibility of number of different combination of parameters. but i want to proceed only with specific arguments. I think its the way to make sure the internal steps executed properly.

Comment: if so I don't believe that you can do better than what you currently do

Comment: can i use custom Matcher, is it add some value or simplify my problem?

Comment: It seems interesting, can you help me to solve it by customizing Matcher. is it a possible to solve it using custom matcher or not?

Comment: what kind of matcher ? argument matcher ?

Comment: Yes, custom argument matcher.

Comment: an argument matcher would only allow to validate that the argument provided is equal to one the expect Request instances, it won't allow you to explicitly associate a Response to a given Request, you will only be able to provide responses corresponding to nth call to the method like I proposed in the first part of the answer, is it good enough?

Comment: The third one does not work for me, complaining NPE when junit sees 2nd stubbing; I guess it needs to go in one line/one statement, at least I find it impossible to mock 3 results with different args. `thenReturn(value1, value2, value3)` works for me.

Answer (score 8):

The proper way would be to match the arguments using `eq()`, but if you don't want to do that, you can just record multiple return values.

```
when(someService.doSomething(any(SomeParam.class))).thenReturn(
  firstReturnValue, secondReturnValue, thirdReturnValue
);
```

Now the first call will return `firstValue`, the second `secondValue` and all following `thirdValue`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are mocking the method just want to verify that the correct arguments are being passed in, you can use any() and verify with ArgumentCaptor following the mocked method call.

Answer (score -1):

I think: the "recommended" way would be the one that WORKS for you; and that comes with the least amount of coding efforts.

You have to have provide THOSE specifications that are necessary to make your test do what it has to do. There is no way around that.

If you really care about the arguments used, then you have to specify them accordingly. If you don't care; use `any()`.

Comment: I also want to use `any()` marcher as well inside. Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "inside"?

Answer (score -1):

the simple solution is to make Mockito silent about this kind of error

```java
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    @MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
```