# EasyMock mock same method with different parameters

Tags: java, mocking, easymock

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767496/mock-same-method-with-different-parameters) but for EasyMock instead of Mockito.

I have some test code like this.

```
expect(mockObject.someMethod("some input", ReturnClassOne.class)).andReturn(returnObjectOne);
expect(mockObject.someMethod("some different input", ReturnClassTwo.class)).andReturn(returnObjectTwo);
```

But this leads to the second line throwing the following exception.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: last method called on mock already has a non-fixed count set.

How can I mock `mockObject.someMethod` to accept two calls with different input params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should perfectly work. EasyMock supports these two recording and will differentiate. For instance, the code below works fine.

So you case is specific. Maybe the `someMethod` signature has something special. I would be interested in having a full test case.

```
public class MyTest {

    public static class ReturnClassOne {}
    public static class ReturnClassTwo {}

    public static class MyClass {

        public <T> T someMethod(String s, Class<T> c) {
            try {
                return c.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        MyClass mockObject = mock(MyClass.class);
        expect(mockObject.someMethod("some input", ReturnClassOne.class)).andReturn(new ReturnClassOne());
        expect(mockObject.someMethod("some different input", ReturnClassTwo.class)).andReturn(new ReturnClassTwo());
        replay(mockObject);
        mockObject.someMethod("some input", ReturnClassOne.class);
        mockObject.someMethod("some different input", ReturnClassTwo.class);
        verify(mockObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right.  What I didn't notice is that in this test file's @Before there was an expect that matched my first expect, and that was what EasyMock was complaining about... it was not complaining about my second expect line.