# Not able to use mocked restTemplate twice

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-resttemplate

I am not able to use mocked restTemplate twice when calling an api with two different request bodies to have two corresponding responses, it’s giving suggestion like check the arguments for mocked resttemplate call. But when I call it for one time it works

`when(dlfRestTemplate.postForObject(“url” , requestBody1, ResponseBdy.class)).thenReturn(response1) when(dlfRestTemplate.postForObject(“url” , requestBody2, ResponseBdy.class)).thenReturn(response2)`

This is how I want to use rest template to mock the api call with two different request bodies.

Comment: Please read this article, I think you will find answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767496/mock-same-method-with-different-parameters

Comment: Thanks for the help Ruslan. I found another easy way to do this. We can use lombok’s @EqualAndHashCode annotation over the class which is being mocked, then after using eq matcher for parameters, we can get unique behaviour for each “when” . This annotation overrides the equal method of the object class to do the equality between the objects based on field values and not the reference.